# Azure SQL Server Firewall

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, firewall

Is there a way to deny public network access and to allow Azure services and resources to access the server? I am using Azure Function with managed identity set up to connect to SQL database and do not want to allow public network access.

[image]

Comment: This looks correct way to setup as Deny public access and allow Azure services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Deny public network access is set to Yes, only connections via private endpoints are allowed. When this setting is No (default), customers can connect by using either public endpoints (with IP-based firewall rules or with virtual-network-based firewall rules) or private endpoints (by using Azure Private Link)

[image]

You have to create Private Endpoint to connect Function to SQL Server as any attempts to set Deny public network access to Yes without any existing private endpoints at the logical server will fail with an error message similar to:

```
Error 42102
Unable to set Deny Public Network Access to Yes since there is no private endpoint enabled to access the server.
Please set up private endpoints and retry the operation.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-settings